# angular 2 Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 error

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

I trying to create a application with angular 2,and have authentication service, when I request to my server get this error:

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

when I use postman everything is ok but use `xhrrequest` throw this error, what is my problem?

Comment: A HTTP status code of 401 means Unauthorized. Maybe you need to send some credentials with your request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that credentials aren't sent for preflighted requests (OPTIONS one) so your server application shouln't check security at this level only for the target request.

But it's an issue on your server side...

This article could interest you:

- **Understanding and using CORS**: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/